# How to set onClickListener on 2d array of button?

Tags: java, android, button, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array of buttons like this

```
b[1][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uno);
b[1][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.due);
b[1][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tre);


b[2][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quattro);
b[2][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cinque);
b[2][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sei);


b[3][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sette);
b[3][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.otto);
b[3][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nove);
```

and i want to get something like

```
b[x][y].setText("X");
```

how I can get the `x` and `y` from the function `onClickListener`?

Comment: Map/SparseArray of Pair/Tuple ... first build it like `sparseArray.append(buttonID, new Pair(x,y))` in the loop ... then obtain in onClick `Pair p = sparseArray.get(view.getId())`

Comment: why do you need the index anyways? If you can directly get the button id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I have used is to create a custom listener class and then create a new listener instance for each cell.

Class:

```
class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    int row;
    int col;

    public MyClickListener(int r, int c) {
        row = r;
        col = c;
    }
    ...
}
```

Setting listeners:

```
for( int r=0; r<3; r++ )
    for( int c=0; c<3; c++ ) {
        screenImages[r][c].setOnClickListener( new MyClickListener(r,c) );
    }
```

Then in the class it is easy to see which row/column was pressed

Answer (score 0):

You can try first

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.uno);
view.setTag(1+""+3);
b[1][3] = view;
```

and then in onClick

```
String s = v.getTag().toString();
int y = Integer.parseInt(TAG.substring(1));
int x = Integer.parseInt(TAG.substring(0,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b[1][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uno);
b[1][3].setTag("1#3");

b[1][3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String tag = (String) v.getTag();
        int x = tag.split("#")[0]; // 1
        int y = tag.split("#")[1]; // 3
    }
});
```